# Cannot access MySQL from remote hosts

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I've been following some documentation and answers all over the place trying to crack this one.

**Scenario**
I want to open my database up for a specfic user for any connection around the world. For arguments sake we will call this user user1.

I have created this user for both localhost and '%' with the following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I have then granted the permissions for this user to connect to only 1 database:

```
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'user1'@'%';
```

Followed by the flush privileges command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I have gone into the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf files and tried both adding and removing the following line:

```
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

Followed by restarting the MySQL service.

I can connect on localhost with this user and do everything I would expect to be able to do but if I connect from a remote host I get the following error (from TOAD Data Point):
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

This is the output from running the following command:

```
netstat -tupln | grep mysql
```

[image: Output from PUTTY]

output from running the nmap command as requested from my remote Windows machine (I've removed the MySQL host for security reasons)
[image: nmap output]

---

servers IP Address for security reasons.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a firewall in place (`iptables`, `ufw`)? From the remote host, can you `nmap $HOSTNAME -p 3306`?

Comment: Everything seems in order, try looking elsewhere.

Comment: I installed iptables but I don't appear to have any services running for it - I'll try nmap and let you know the output

Comment: @StefanM I have added the output of the nmap command for you to my question

Comment: Have you tried connecting using MySql Workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything for the Ubuntu setup was absolutely correct the reason that this wasn't working is simply because the server host 1&1 have their own firewall separate to the firewall I had installed on the Ubuntu instance.

Once I had changed the rules on the 1&1 firewall everything worked as expected.

Thanks for everyone's help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You must open the port MySQL is listening on your machine. The default port is 3306. You should accept incoming TCP connections on this port. 
Or you can disable firewall which is not recommended.